# html preview from html file on github

Tags: html, css, github

I'ld like to be able to visualize correctly my html files on one of my github repository.
I tried with https://htmlpreview.github.io/
it partially works.
https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/pdeman/mevislabFetalMRI/blob/master/Documentation/Publish/ModuleReference/index.html

but part of the pages is behind the sidebar.

the sidebar is defined in https://github.com/pdeman/mevislabFetalMRI/blob/master/Documentation/Publish/ModuleReference/_static/basic.css
and this css doesn't seem to be loaded correctly. at least I don't see it here:
[image]

I tried to add:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_static/basic.css" type="text/css" />
```

in the html file, then I see that basic.css is loaded but the sidebar is still on top of the main sections.

if I add :

```
left: 200px;
```

in div.document for example, then I don't have the overlay in html preview.
but I have a 200px white gap in between my sidebar and my document when opening directly the file on a browser.
somehow it seems to not use the same position reference between htmlpreview.github.io and opening it normally.

how can I have the side bar not over the main text ?

Comment: I think you should create github.io page first check the https://guides.github.com/features/pages/

Comment: but then I need to re do all my html/css pages in the .yml style ? I am not sure to have understood how works the github pages...

Comment: most of my html/css are semiautomatically created by the software mevislab. I don't want to have to recode them if there is a possibility tousing html visualize them correctly using htmlpreview